# content of the package declaration

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

How can I see the content of the description aria of a package and specific types?(pl sql)

For example in package p1 I have 3 functions `f1, f2, f3`; 2 procedures `p1, p2` and 2 variables `v1, v2`.

I need a list with 2 columns: one for name (`f1, f2` etc) and one for the type (function, procedure, variable etc).

Answer (score 3):

You can find details about the functions and procedures in a package by querying the [ALL_ARGUMENTS](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_1014.htm) data dictionary view, or its brethren USER_ARGUMENTS and DBA_ARGUMENTS.

For an example I created the following package:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE demo AS
    PROCEDURE p_none;
    PROCEDURE p_two(a INTEGER, b INTEGER);

    FUNCTION f_none RETURN INTEGER;
    FUNCTION f_three(c INTEGER, q INTEGER, z INTEGER) RETURN INTEGER;
END;
```

I then ran the following query against it:

```
SQL> select object_name, argument_name, sequence, in_out
  2    from all_arguments
  3   where package_name = 'DEMO'
  4   order by object_name, sequence;

OBJECT_NAME                    ARGUMENT_NAME                    SEQUENCE IN_OUT
------------------------------ ------------------------------ ---------- ---------
F_NONE                                                                 1 OUT
F_THREE                                                                1 OUT
F_THREE                        C                                       2 IN
F_THREE                        Q                                       3 IN
F_THREE                        Z                                       4 IN
P_NONE                                                                 0 IN
P_TWO                          A                                       1 IN
P_TWO                          B                                       2 IN
```

Here you can see all of the arguments to the functions and procedures in our package.  Note that there is an extra entry with a null argument name for the return value for each of the two functions.  Also, the procedure that has no arguments has a row with a null argument name and a zero `SEQUENCE` value.

So, to list all functions, you could search for all entries in this view with a null argument name and a `SEQUENCE` value not equal to 0:

```
SQL> select distinct object_name
  2    from all_arguments
  3   where package_name = 'DEMO'
  4     and argument_name is null
  5     and sequence != 0;

OBJECT_NAME
------------------------------
F_THREE
F_NONE
```

Listing procedures in a similar way is a little trickier:

```
SQL> select distinct object_name
  2    from all_arguments a1
  3   where package_name = 'DEMO'
  4     and (   sequence = 0
  5          or not exists (select 0
  6                           from all_arguments a2
  7                          where a2.package_name = 'DEMO'
  8                            and a2.object_name = a1.object_name
  9                            and a2.argument_name is null));

OBJECT_NAME
------------------------------
P_TWO
P_NONE
```

While this approach appears to work with procedures and functions, I don't know how to list the package-scope variables, types and other things declared within a package header without parsing the package spec, as suggested by @wweicker.

Comment: Changed in 18c: procedures with no args (like P_NONE above) will not appear in all_arguments. You can see it only in all_procedures.

Answer (score 1):

This is no trivial task! You'll have to parse the package specification by looping through the lines, i.e.

```
  select *
    from all_source
   where owner = '<the package owner>'
     and name = '<the package name>'
     and type = 'PACKAGE'
order by line;
```